# sed to replace string with partial match

Tags: regex, sed

In a file, I want to replace

`init_connections=yyy` with `init_connections=100`

If I use  `sed -i 's/init_connections=*/init_connections=80/g'`, it changes `init_connections=yyy` to `init_connections=100yyy` which is not intended.

`yyy` in string varies, hence I cannot have it fixed in `sed` command. Can you please help how I can replace `init_connections=<anything>` with `init_connections=100`?

Comment: `=*` means one or more `=` characters. [Regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) ≠ [glob](https://linux.die.net/man/7/glob).

Comment: See also: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)